Laravel reverb in production : should i run php artisan reverb:start on my vps.?
I downloaded Laravel with Reverb on my local server and everything is working perfectly.
but laravel reverb dont work without  php artisan reverb:start in production envirement .. should i run php artisan reverb:start to make it work ?
this is my nginx setup
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    root /path/to/public;
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 

    charset utf-8;
 
     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
    error_page 404 /index.php;
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }
 
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

  location /app {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }
{{certbot cert}}

}
{{certbot cert}}


If you're using forge, forge will handle it for you. if not you can use Supervisor with ubuntu

yes supervisor is the correct answer .. thanks

If the server is running Linux, the solution is to create a supervisor.
Create supervisor
sudo nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-reverb.conf

Put this code :
[program:laravel-reverb]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /path-to-your-laravel-app/artisan reverb:start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=your-user
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laravel-reverb.log

Run this commands:
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl start laravel-reverb:*

Note :
You can name the file laravel-reverb whatever you want.

Previous Answer is absolutely correct, but for me was few problems
CentOS7
Supervisor don't see conf file so I created INI file in folder supervisors.d
sudo nano /etc/supervisord.d/laravel-reverb.ini

Next problem was PHP version, coz by default it 5.4 too old. Check version for root user
php -v 
sudo ln -sf /path_to_another_php_ver/php83/bin/php /usr/bin/php

sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl restart laravel-reverb:*

